# Can't install published Adobe AIR application

Tags: air

Hi I create a flash game using adobe flash player 6 (AIR).
If I test it using "Test Scene", it run very well.
I set it to run on Adobe AIR desktop target 3.2 (my PC is 4.0)
I publish the game in format .air and create  a certificate.

**The problem : I can't install my game (in AIR package) on my computer.**

The warning is:The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author.

I already use administrator  account but it does n't work. Can you help me??

Comment: Sorry, looks like I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is because my system clock is not accurate and I use self certificate (using time stamp).
So, I must repair my system clock and publish adobe AIR application again with new certificate.